# 401 response with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, rtsp

I'am using library "requests" for get image from url ('http://any_login:any_password@10.10.9.2/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101/picture?snapShotImageType=JPEG'), but response error with code 401. Thats url from my rtsp camera.

I try using 'HTTPBasicAuth', 'HTTPDigestAuth' and 'HTTPProxyAuth'. But it's not working.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "http://any_login:any_password@10.10.9.2/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101/picture?snapShotImageType=JPEG"
response = requests.get(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("any_login", "any_password"))

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("sample.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

I expected the output of image file from rtsp flow, but I got error code 401.

Comment: `401` means the request in unauthorized. Are you providing the right credentials?

Comment: Does the link work e.g. in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I providing the right credentials. I can get image from browser with that's credentials.

Comment: This link works excellent in other browser.

Comment: add the headers and try it

Comment: are you sure it shouldn't be `requests.post` instead of `requests.get`?

Comment: `any_login:any_password@10.10.9.2`  part of URL already carries the auth information. AFAIK, this is an old style. Remove that from the URL and try with host only and Basic authentication `http://10.10.9.2/..`

Answer (score 1):

Given your username I suspect your password may contain non-ASCII characters.  I had a similar issue with a password containing diacritics.

This worked :

```
curl -u user:pwd --basic https://example.org
```

This (and variations) throwed `401 Unauthorized` :

```
import requests
requests.get("https://example.org", auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("user","pwd"))
```

Changing the password to ASCII only characters solved the issue.